# Using anonymous vs nested class in an infinite loop (Java)

Tags: java, anonymous-class

What is better in the context of an infinite loop : an anonymous class or a nested class ?
As I see it , if we use an anonymous class it's redefined for each iteration , but using a nested class we still create an instance , but the class itself is not redefined. Not sure if this is correct...  Is there any advantage of using one vs the other in this situation ?

```
public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        while (true) {
        final int data = rand.nextInt();
        //Runnable task = new MyRunnable(data);
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                printData(data);
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
        }
    }

    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private int data;

        MyRunnable(int data){
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            printData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous inner classes are not "redefined for each call" - they should have exactly the same overhead as an inner class, with the exception that your inner class is static and therefore avoids keeping a reference to the external `this`, if any.

If you compile the above program, you will see several generated classes:

```
MainThread$1.class
MainThread.class
MainThread$MyRunnable.class
```

Decompiling the $1 (= your inner anonymous class) and the $MyRunnable (= your inner named class) shows that they are essentially identical:

```
  MainThread$1(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: iload_1       
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field val$data:I
       5: aload_0       
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       9: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #1                  // Field val$data:I
       4: invokestatic  #3                  // Method MainThread.printData:(I)V
       7: return
```

And

```
class MainThread$MyRunnable implements java.lang.Runnable {
  MainThread$MyRunnable(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: iload_1       
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field data:I
       9: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field data:I
       4: invokestatic  #3                  // Method MainThread.printData:(I)V
       7: return        
}
```

The only difference is that the anonymous inner class is not storing 'data' in its constructor, and is instead reading it from an external static final variable.